# Firefox - Selenium - Python - Download an image from URL rather than opening in Tab

Tags: selenium, firefox, automation, selenium-firefoxdriver

Background:
I am trying to download files, among them some images, from a series of URLs.
The majority of files are downloaded as I've used the `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` setting to included every MIME type listed in the system.

Because the site requires authentication I am using Selenium & Python to automate the login and then sequentially execute driver.get(URL) to get the files; using requests doesn't work because of the authentication.

Problem:
Some files (specifically txt, jpg & gif) open in the tab and therefore aren't downloaded.

What I need Firefox to do is open the image URL and download the file rather than open it.

Example URL for behavior - not from the actual site as it's a corporate system:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZBRw.png

Even with text/plain, image/jpeg and image/gif added to `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` they still open in the tab.

The MIME types are sent correctly from the server, tested with Fiddler.

I can find no override for the behavior in Firefox, never mind with Selenium controlling it. If I could I would override the settings and build a profile to import or automate modifying the settings in some way.

```
firefoxProfile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefoxProfile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
firefoxProfile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
firefoxProfile.set_preference("browser.download.dir",sDownloadDir)
firefoxProfile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled",True)
firefoxProfile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","image/bmp,image/gif,image/x-gif,image/jpeg,image/x-jpeg,image/png,image/tif,image/tiff,image/x-ms-bmp,image/x-png,image/x-portable-bitmap,text/plain")
```

Tried adding image/x-jpeg and image/x-gif as above because BMP files were downloading but that hasn't helped.

Comment: the webdriver cannot access the DOM if it's not there, so a browser window that does not display HTML won't be automate-able.  Basically those files are already downloaded/cached by the browser... you just have to find them.  (Maybe use a tool that views the browser's cache...)

Comment: another option would be to screenshot the specific element.  (you can use the webdriver for that...)